# How to check whether C# DateTime is within a range

Tags: c#, datetime

In C# I have *from* and *to* DateTime vales and want to check whether a *value* DateTime is within the range, how can I do this?

```
lowerBound = "01-Dec-2011 09:45:58"
upperBound = "01-Dec-2011 09:38:58"
value = "01-Dec-2011 09:49:58"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553663/how-to-determine-if-birthday-or-anniversary-occured-during-date-range

Answer (score 7):

Just use the comparison operators as you would for numbers:

```
DateTime lowerBound = new DateTime(2011, 12, 1, 9, 38, 58);
DateTime upperBound = new DateTime(2011, 12, 1, 9, 49, 58);
DateTime value = new DateTime(2011, 12, 1, 9, 45, 58);

// This is an inclusive lower bound and an exclusive upper bound.
// Adjust to taste.
if (lowerBound <= value && value < upperBound)
```

You'll need to be careful that the values are all the same "kind" (UTC, local, unspecific). If you're trying to compare *instants* in time, (e.g. "did X happen before Y") it's probably best to use UTC.

Comment: Use Between function to get value  between lowerBound  and upperBound

Comment: @SreenathPlakkat: Which `Between` function are you referring to? Sounds more like SQL than C#...

Comment: @Jon Skeet - also note, that Kind property of DateTime is ignored during the comparison.

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli: Indeed, which is why it makes sense to only use operands with the same kind, really. Anything else is likely to lead to confusion.