# How do I determine if a date lies between current week dates?

Tags: c#

In C#,

How we are check certain date with in week dates?

Eg: 6/02/2014

Current Weeks: 02/02/2014 - 08/02/2014

so this dates are with in above week....

Comment: How do you think week starts? On sunday? On monday?

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you are asking. Can you provide a more detailed description?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599895/find-the-current-week-from-datetime-now-and-how-to-find-given-date-between-curre (the same author of question)

Answer (score 5):

Use this for check (last parameter is optional if you want always 1 week from fromDate, you don't need use last parameter):

```
 public static bool DateInside(DateTime checkDate, 
     DateTime fromDate, DateTime? lastDate = null)
 {
     DateTime toDate = lastDate != null ? lastDate.Value : fromDate.AddDays(6d);
     return checkDate >= fromDate && checkDate <= toDate;
 }
```

To call use:

```
bool isDateInside = DateInside(new DateTime(2014, 02, 06), 
     new DateTime(2014, 02, 02)); // return true
```

And search first :) Answer is also here: [How to check whether C# DateTime is within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337251/how-to-check-whether-c-sharp-datetime-is-within-a-range)

If you want to **check if the dates are inside the same week**, then you can use this:

```
public static bool DateInsideOneWeek(DateTime checkDate, DateTime referenceDate)
{
    // get first day of week from your actual culture info, 
    DayOfWeek firstWeekDay = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
    // or you can set exactly what you want: firstWeekDay = DayOfWeek.Monday;
    // calculate first day of week from your reference date
    DateTime startDateOfWeek = referenceDate;
    while(startDateOfWeek.DayOfWeek != firstWeekDay)
    { startDateOfWeek = startDateOfWeek.AddDays(-1d); }
    // fist day of week is find, then find last day of reference week
    DateTime endDateOfWeek = startDateOfWeek.AddDays(6d);
    // and check if checkDate is inside this period
    return checkDate >= startDateOfWeek && checkDate <= endDateOfWeek;
}
```

Actual week in my culture info start with monday, February 3th 2014 (so for me is week between February 3th and February 9th). If I check any date with reference date (second parameter) as today (2014-Feb-06) I get this results:

```
For 2014-Feb-02 (Sunday before this week): false
For 2014-Feb-03 (Monday inside this week): true
For 2014-Feb-06 (Today  inside this week): true
For 2014-Feb-09 (Sunday inside this week): true
For 2014-Feb-10 (Monday next        week): false
```

You can call this method to check if one date is inside the same week as referentional like this:

```
DateInsideOneWeek(new DateTime(2014, 02, 02), new DateTime(2014, 02, 06));
```

You can find **current week start and end dates** with this code:

```
DateTime startDateOfWeek = DateTime.Now.Date; // start with actual date
while(startDateOfWeek.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday) // set first day of week in your country
{ startDateOfWeek = startDateOfWeek.AddDays(-1d); } // after this while loop you get first day of actual week
DateTime endDateOfWeek = startDateOfWeek.AddDays(6d); // you just find last week day
```

Is this you wanted?

Comment: How we have to find Current Week Dates? Then Check corresponding date with in the week dates?

Comment: I extended my answer for what I think you want. Please, check if this is you wanted and if not, modify your question and explain it.

Answer (score 1):

hmm

```
public bool isBetween(DateTime input, DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
    {
        if (input > date1 && input < date2)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

?

input= your date
date1 & date2 = start and end of a week

Comment: in above only for example. We need to find first wat are all current week days then need to check corresponding given date?

Comment: Yes but this is very simple task. You can get current day of the week and from this you can count starting date and ending date

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
bool inRange = (date >= lowerDate && date <= upperDate);
```

Comment: I think OP wants to get given date has which weeks(and what are the dates this week start and end). Of course question is not clear at all..

Comment: @SonerGönül - possibly. It's not 100% clear what is being asked :-(

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution :)

```
public static class DateExtensions
{
    private static void Swap<T>(ref T one, ref T two)
    {
        var temp = one;
        one = two;
        two = temp;
    }

    public static bool IsFromSameWeek(this DateTime first, DateTime second, DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        // sort dates
        if (first > second)
        {
            Swap(ref first, ref second);
        }

        var daysDiff = (second - first).TotalDays;
        if (daysDiff >= 7)
        {
            return false;
        }

        const int TotalDaysInWeek = 7;
        var adjustedDayOfWeekFirst = (int)first.DayOfWeek + (first.DayOfWeek < firstDayOfWeek ? TotalDaysInWeek : 0);
        var adjustedDayOfWeekSecond = (int)second.DayOfWeek + (second.DayOfWeek < firstDayOfWeek ? TotalDaysInWeek : 0);

        return adjustedDayOfWeekSecond >= adjustedDayOfWeekFirst;
    }
}
```

Upd: it appears to have at least twice better performance than @Atiris solution :)