# Find the Current Week from Datetime.Now and How to find given Date between current week dates?

Tags: c#

1) How do I find Current Week from Current Date time in C#?

2) Then we have to find given date, Is Exist on corresponding Week dates?

Pls assists  to me for solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "Current Week"? The 1st through 52nd week of the year?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I determine if a date lies between current week dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598365/how-do-i-determine-if-a-date-lies-between-current-week-dates)

Comment: This looks a lot like you've just asked the same question twice? Can you rephrase this one to focus on your 1st question?

Answer (score 4):

```
int currentWeek = (DateTime.Now.DayOfYear / 7) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Calendar.

```
Calendar cal = new Calendar();
int week = cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime time, calendarWeekRule rule, DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek);
```

Check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To get week number of any given date:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
int weekNo = culture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
            new DateTime(YOUR_GIVEN_DATE_HERE),
            currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
            currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
```

Just replace YOUR_GIVEN_DATE_HERE with Datetime.Now (for current date) or your any given date.
If the weekNos are equal then they are in the same week.
That will solve both of your questions.