# Why my C# program doesn't display Birthday reminders?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code written into my main class (C#) for the Birthday reminders. It used to work but now it doesn't. I haven't changed the code at all. What the problem could be?

```
/// <summary>
/// Find all members that have birthdays occurring this week
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Returns an ArrayList containing members</returns>
public ArrayList BirthdaysThisWeek()
{
    ArrayList members = new ArrayList();

    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

    //Work out how many days to add or to take away to get us to Monday
    int delta = DayOfWeek.Monday - today.DayOfWeek;
    //Change the date to point to Monday
    DateTime monday = today.AddDays(delta);
    //Make this date point to Sunday
    DateTime sunday = monday.AddDays(6);

    foreach (Member member in allMembers)
    {
        DateTime dob = member.DateOfBirth.Date;
        //Check to see if a member's birthdate is between Monday and Sunday
        if(dob >= monday.Date && dob <= sunday.Date)
        {
            //Add member to members ArrayList
            members.Add(member);
        }
    }

    //Return all members that have a birthday this week if none were     found return an empty ArrayList
    return members;
}
```

Comment: Is this Winforms/WPF (client) or ASP.Net (server)? If the latter it could be a change to the datetime settings on the server

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Does it miss some specific members? Specific days? Does it return anything at all?

Comment: You compare the date including the years, not only the day and month part. None of the members is born this week in this year

Comment: It is using ASP.Net (server).

Comment: It doesn't return anything when running the program and setting the members birthday for e.g. tomorrow etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553663/how-to-determine-if-birthday-or-anniversary-occured-during-date-range

Comment: I have exactly the same type of a code for licence due date and that works fine, returning the reminder. I don't understand where the problem could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition not work because you compare year, month, and day of Birthday with dates of actual week. I changed my answer after the remark of **CodeCaster** , because DayOfYear don't work with birthdays after February 28th in leap years, you can solve this by initialize `dob` DateTime like this :

```
int actuelYear = member.DateOfBirth.Month == monday.Month ? monday.Year : sunday.Year;
DateTime dob = new DateTime(actuelYear, member.DateOfBirth.Month, member.DateOfBirth.Day);
if (dob.Date >= monday.Date && dob.Date <= sunday.Date)
{
    members.Add(member);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for edit Jeremy :)

Comment: Thank you very much Abdellah, it is working! Thanks to everyone else for trying to help too.

Comment: My pleasure, your answer is actually better than mine. I forgot about the `DayOfYear` method. Using that is really eloquent for this task.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that !

Comment: @LanaDeGeeve - when you ask a question you will see to the left of each answer a holo TickBox. Ticking the correct answer lets others know your query is solved and gives you a couple of points. Good luck!

Comment: `Date.DayOfYear` won't work with birthdays after February 28th in leap years. [March 1st will have a different value in such years](http://ideone.com/3VhJSh).

Comment: @CodeCaster You are right, Thanks for your important remark, I have change the  answer to resolve that. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless they were born this week, I dont see how this will work.

You need to disregard the Year in which they were born.

```
public static bool IsBirthDayInRange(DateTime birthday, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    DateTime temp = birthday.AddYears(start.Year - birthday.Year);

    if (temp < start) temp = temp.AddYears(1);

    return birthday <= end && temp >= start && temp <= end;
}
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2554881/495455

So you need to change your code to this:

```
public ArrayList BirthdaysThisWeek()
{
    ArrayList members = new ArrayList();

    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    int delta = DayOfWeek.Monday - today.DayOfWeek;
    DateTime monday = today.AddDays(delta);
    DateTime sunday = monday.AddDays(6);

    foreach (Member member in allMembers)
    {
        DateTime dob = member.DateOfBirth.Date;

        //Check to see if a member's birthdate is between Monday and Sunday
        if (IsBirthDayInRange(dob, monday, sunday)
        {
            //Add member to members ArrayList
            members.Add(member);
        }
    }
    return members;
}
```

Comment: How should I rewrite the code to resolve this matter? I am totally new to this.

Comment: The `IsBirthDayInRange` method is good, its Object Orientated Programming using something like this as its Reusable, Encapsulated, Abstract and Polymorphic. For example say if you wanted to know the Birthdays each Month, Bi-Month, Quarter or etc - it will do the job for all applications.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions of concerns and welcome to [so]!